# Custom search bar header onchange function react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have created a custom header and search bar in my react native project. And I called both the header and search bar in my main component. I want to make a hot search. Like when users start entering the first letter itself the filter wants to work. Already I have filtered the data using button like (ALL, Item1, Item2) if user clicks (All) and they searched anything in search bar the items should get filtered. Now my problem is, Since I am having the separate class function for search bar and I am calling that class into my main Component. Where I want to write onchange function. Please correct me if my coding structure was wrong and help me to achieve the output. Thanks in advance. Below is my code for header and main component.

```
class SearchBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
          borderRadius: 12,
          color: "#8E8E93",
          flexDirection: "row",
          fontSize: 18,
          height: 100,
          width: config.deviceWidth * 0.89,
          margin: 25,
          marginVertical: 10,
          paddingHorizontal: 20,
          marginTop: config.deviceWidth * 0.27,
          marginRight: 20,
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Search Product/Stores"
          style={{ fontSize: 15, paddingLeft: 2, alignItems: "center" }}
        />
        <Icon
          name="ios-search"
          style={{ fontSize: 25, paddingLeft: config.deviceWidth * 0.28 }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class MainComponent extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
      headerRight: <SearchBar />
    }

}

    constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
        isLoading: true
    }
    }
    
    render() {
    return(
    
     Here I am using FlatList to populate the data 
    )
    }
```

Comment: what's it currently showing and what do you want it to show? I kind of understand what you want it to show, just not what it's currently showing

Comment: As of now I brought button based filter. And now I need to do hot search when the user click any letter in search box . My doubt is I have wrote the search box class separately. I have called the search bar component in my main component. My doubt is where I want to write onchnage function.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the function to your main component class and pass the function as a prop to the search component class.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [React docs on Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), it is applicable here.  When you have multiple components that depend on a shared state value, that state should be owned by the highest up component in the group and passed down to the others through props.  Props can be anything: string, functions, other components, etc.

In this case `enteredText` (or whatever you want to call it) belongs in the state of `MainComponent`.  `MainComponent` also needs to own a function to update that text to a new value via `setState`.  This could be a function of the event, but personally I would make it be a function of the text and handle the mapping of event to text (`e => e.target.value`) further down in the tree because that is more flexible as it doesn't tie the logic of `MainComponent` to any particular event type. It doesn't make any difference in this case, but if you read up separating logic from presentation you'll start to see.

When `MainComponent` calls `<SearchBar />` it should include both the text and the update function in the props, which would look something like

```
<SearchBar
   text={this.state.enteredText}
   onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
/>
```

or

```
<SearchBar
   text={this.state.enteredText}
   onChangeText={e => this.setState({enteredText: e.target.value})}
/>
```

or however else you want to set it up.

`SearchBar` then passes these props down to `TextInput`, which also needs to receive a value and some sort of callback to update that value.